# Gnome Terminal appearance

Tags: terminal, gnome3, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to get the gnome-terminal in GNOME 3 to be borderless, similar to how urxvt looks? Without the big top of it that says Terminal with your working directory or the menu bar?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the menu bar for gnome-terminal in its application menu (in Gnome 3 this is a drop down in the top bar). You can also edit your default profile to not include scroll bars, the menu bar, etc in net terminals.

Beyond that, the window chrome (the border, title bar, etc) are decided on and drawn by your window manager (in Gnome 3 this is Mutter). I don't think there is an easy way to make Mutter not draw borders on some windows, but you can check the Gnome extension library for something that does that.

Comment: This is not about the menu bar, but about the header bar. The version in Ubuntu 20.04 (I saw that your answer is much older than that), gnome-terminal draws the header bar, and its own window borders, even though I am not in Gnome. I suppose Gnome considers that the use of gnome-terminal outside of Gnome is unsupported.

Comment: @Gauthier I'm quite aware what the question was. The thing you are calling the header bar is still considered window decoration and drawn by system libraries not the app. The situation has changed since this answer now that CSD (Client Side Decorations) are a common thing. How to turn them off now in Gnome (or on behalf of Gnome libraries no matter your DE is) I don't know. I can say that when I run `gnome-terminal` on my system under `awesome` that there is not only no menubar (because I disabled it) but there is no header bar or other decorations (which I have disabled in Awesome WM).

Comment: Thanks for this clarification! I'm in a similar situation, where my xmonad and dwm have never drawn title or header bar for me. I recently ran `startx` manually from a tty (ctrl+alt+f3), and since then my gnome-terms in xmonad displays header bars and window borders. But not in dwm?!

Comment: @Gauthier I think the way this works is that the toolkit libraries (GTk/Gnome stuff that draw the window in this case) first *ask* whether the DE is going to draw decorations or not. If it gets told no, then it draws them itself. If it gets told yes, it doesn't do anything — which is what your `dwm` and my `awesome` are telling it. Even though they don't plan an drawing decorations themselves, they tell apps that it's taken care of so they don't try to take it on themselves. I'm sure there is a way to toll the libraries to always assume a yes answer too, but I don't know what that is.

Answer (score -1):

Enabling compiz, will give a large selection of effects like borderless windows.
I am using Terminal without window border also, I don't use compiz, but when I open my terminal window, I click on F11 to make it full screen.

If you want to hide the menu bar also, click on : "View" -> disable "Show menubar".